# What will run faster?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I made this thumbnail rotator in javascript, and figured it could be written shorter as seen in the first example, however will this help performance? and are there any general guidelines you should follow in order to maximize javascript speed? (pardon my ugly code, I'm very new to the game)

```
function mouseOverfirst(videoId){
            var num = 8;
            var numb = 7;
            $('#'+videoId).attr('src',videoId+'/thumb'+numb+'.png');
            if(numb == 7){
            interval = setInterval(function(){
             $('#'+videoId).attr('src',videoId+'/thumb'+num+'.png');   
                if(num == 15){
                    num = 1;
                }    
                else
                {
                    num++;
                }
            },500);
        }
    }
```

or this?

```
function mouseOverfirst(videoId){
            var numb = 7;
            $('#'+videoId).attr('src',videoId+'/thumb'+numb+'.png');
            if(numb == 7){
                mouseOver('video1');
            }
}

function mouseOver(videoId){
            var num = 8;
            interval = setInterval(function(){
             $('#'+videoId).attr('src',videoId+'/thumb'+num+'.png');   
                if(num == 15){
                    num = 1;
                }    
                else
                {
                    num++;
                }
            },500);
        }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? did you make separate slides of the image rotating?

Comment: I doesn't seem as if your variables `num`  or `numb` can change after declaration, so why do you need the if statement?

Comment: You seem to care about performance, yet you use `$("#"+videoId).attr('src', ...)` instead of the indescribably faster `document.getElementById(videoId).src = ...` - you're looking for optimisations in the wrong places.

Comment: If you want to make it run faster, decrease the interval from 500ms to, say, 200ms. *SCNR*

Comment: This code is absolutely not performance-sensitive. [Don't try to optimise that](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation). Rather, learn to write more beautiful code!

Comment: brianxautumn As i stated, this is a very messy code, and i understand that it's hard to see it's functionality. Essentially, I didn't want the 500ms delay to apply to the first swap, but make it so that it instantly swapped to a new picture on hover, and from there rotated trough the thumbnails with the delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The complexity of both programs are the same.

It doesn't matter which one you use, but the 2nd one is more approachable as a function `mouseOverFirst` and `mouseOver` can be reused easily.